# Regular expressions to replace text strings in a MS Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, wildcards

I have the following protocol names like GR232 or GR485 and I am looking to replace them with the expression "GR" followed by a hyphen and the appropriate three digit number, something like GR-232 or GR-485.
I have tried with MS Word, but I always get the same error

Find what: (<[a-zA-Z]>){2;} (<[0-9]>){2;}

Replace with: (<[a-zA-Z]>)-(<[0-9]>)

So far I am just learning everything related to Microsoft regular expressions, so I can't think of a solution. I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Word regular expression is not true regular expression. If you want real regular expression in MS Word, VBA is the way to go. A good place to learn how to use MS Word wildcards: [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm).

What you asked can be done in MS Word. However, there are few issues with your regular expression:

- `;`: is invalid inside curly braces when trying to find at least/maximum characters. `,` must be used.
- The captured expression are replaced with `\1`, `\2`, etc not by the regular expression `(<[a-zA-Z]>)` or others.

Try the following:

- Find what: `<([a-zA-Z]{2,})([0-9]{2,})>`
- Replace with: `\1-\2`
- Select `Use wildcards`
- Press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Dear @Reddy Lutonadio, thank you very much for your collaboration, I will take your recommendations into account!